# How do i fix my pipe in linux socket program?

Tags: c, linux

I included some of my code ,when i run my program (server) everything works fine except for the pipe i am really not sure where to problem is, the output always prints 0 and both error messages get printed out.(dots represent chunks of code i left out)
First the program makes connection with client and then the communication begins, at the end of communication pipe in child process is suppose to send variable hours to pipe in the parent process.

```
#define PORT 4444
#define BUF_SIZE 2000
#define CLADDR_LEN 100

void func(int subor,int rychlost,int *h,int *m,int *s){

    int hours,minutes,seconds,inputSecond;
    int remainingSeconds;
    
    int secondsInHour = 60 * 60;
    int secondsInMinute = 60;
    
    
    
    subor *= 8000;
    rychlost *= 1000;
    
    inputSecond = subor/rychlost;

    hours = (inputSecond/secondsInHour);


    remainingSeconds = inputSecond - (hours * secondsInHour);
    minutes = remainingSeconds/secondsInMinute;


    remainingSeconds = remainingSeconds - (minutes*secondsInMinute);
    seconds = remainingSeconds;
    
    *h=hours;
    *m=minutes;
    *s=seconds;

}

void main() {
 struct sockaddr_in addr, cl_addr;
 int sockfd, len, ret, newsockfd,fileSize,speed;
 char buffer[BUF_SIZE]="Type 'start' or 'exit'\n";
 pid_t childpid;
 int hours,minutes,seconds;
 int fd[2];

 
 sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
 if (sockfd < 0) {
  printf("Error creating socket!\n");
  exit(1);
 }
 printf("Socket created...\n");
 
 memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
 addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
 addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
 addr.sin_port = PORT;
 
 ret = bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &addr, sizeof(addr));
 if (ret < 0) {
  printf("Error binding!\n");
  exit(1);
 }
 printf("Binding done...\n");

 printf("Waiting for a connection...\n");
 listen(sockfd, 5);

 for (;;) { 
  len = sizeof(cl_addr);
  newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cl_addr, &len);
  if (newsockfd < 0) {
   printf("Error accepting connection!\n");
   exit(1);
  }
  printf("Connection accepted...\n");


  if ((childpid = fork()) == 0) { 
    close(fd[0]);
   close(sockfd); 


        ret = send(newsockfd, buffer, BUF_SIZE, 0);   
    if (ret < 0) {  
     printf("Error sending data!\n");  
     exit(1);  
    }  
    
   for (;;) {
    memset(buffer, 0, BUF_SIZE);
    

    
    ret = recv(newsockfd, buffer, BUF_SIZE, 0);
    if(ret < 0) {
     printf("Error receiving data!\n");  
     exit(1);
    }
 
     
       if (strcmp(buffer, "start\n") == 0)  {
       
        ret = send(newsockfd, "Type size of file in [Mb]\n", BUF_SIZE, 0);   
        if (ret < 0) {  
         printf("Error sending data!\n");  
         exit(1);  
        }  
        
            ret = recv(newsockfd, buffer, BUF_SIZE, 0);
            if(ret < 0) {
             printf("Error receiving data!\n");  
             exit(1);
            }
         
        fileSize = atoi(buffer);
         
         ret = send(newsockfd, "Type Speed of internet in [MB]\n", BUF_SIZE, 0);   
          if (ret < 0) {  
          printf("Error sending data!\n");  
          exit(1);  
            } 
             
          ret = recv(newsockfd, buffer, BUF_SIZE, 0);
            if(ret < 0) {
             printf("Error receiving data!\n");  
             exit(1);
            }
         
        speed = atoi(buffer);
        
        func(fileSize,speed,&hours,&minutes,&seconds);
        
        buffer[BUF_SIZE] = sprintf(buffer,"Upload bude trvat %d:%d:%d\n",hours,minutes,seconds);
        
        
        if((write(fd[1], &hours,sizeof(int))) == -1){   \\problem is here
            printf("write error\n"); 
            }
        close(fd[1]);
        
        ret = send(newsockfd, buffer, BUF_SIZE, 0);   
          if (ret < 0) {  
          printf("Error sending data!\n");  
          exit(1);  
            } 
             
        exit(0); 
            }
    
   }
  }else{
    wait();
    close(fd[1]);
    int fin;
    

    if((read(fd[0], &fin, sizeof(int))) == -1){   \\problem is here
    printf("read error\n"); 
    }
 
    
    
    printf("%d\n",fin); 
    close(fd[0]);
  }
  close(newsockfd);
 }
}
```

Comment: Please, read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in order to know how you can post a testable piece of code.  If we need to make your program runnable first, we can correct the problem you are stuck on in the way, and see no problem at all afterwards.  Also, if you don't test your snippet of code, how do you know that the problem is still there?  Talking about a problem is not the same as showing a problem.  Follow the link above and edit your code to become a fully testable program.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile.  It has syntax errors.  What should we do now?

Comment: What do you mean with _Problem is here_? and most important, why do you know that is there, if you mark two places as _problem is here_ in the code (by the way, you use two backslash characters to start a comment, instead of starting a comment with `//` which is a more desirable thing to do.  Why have you eliminated all the `#include`s neede to compile your code?  Wont you think it should be desirable to put them in your snippet so we don't have to spend 20min over your compilation errors to get all the errors eliminated to see how in your code _everything works fine except for the pipe_ ???

Comment: This question is not `linux` related, so please, edit the question and take that tag off.  Add `sockets` if you consider it, but linux is not special to make a tag for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after solving some of the problems in the code you sent, I think I've got your code running:

```
$ netstat -p -l | grep pru28763
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:23569           0.0.0.0:*               ESCUCHAR    46607/pru28763      
$ _
```

your process is actually listening, but not in port `4444`, but in port `46607`.
This means you have not converted the port number into network byte order by calling `htons()` macro.  And you need to do.

I'll send you a diff with all the corrections made to your code, to make it run, but you don't initialize the array `fd[]` and, as I don't know how do you want to use it (there's no call to `pipe(2)` in your posted code)  I cannot further help you:

```
diff --git a/pru28763.c b/pru28763.c
index 78792e9..a6b7c7d 100644
--- a/pru28763.c
+++ b/pru28763.c
@@ -57,7 +57,7 @@ void main() {
  memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
  addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
- addr.sin_port = PORT;
+ addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
  
  ret = bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &addr, sizeof(addr));
  if (ret < 0) {
@@ -84,7 +84,7 @@ void main() {
    close(sockfd); 
 
 
-        ret = send(newsockfd, buffer, BUF_SIZE, 0);   
+        ret = send(newsockfd, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0);   
     if (ret < 0) {  
      printf("Error sending data!\n");  
      exit(1);  
@@ -102,25 +102,32 @@ void main() {
     }
  
      
-       if (strcmp(buffer, "start\n") == 0)  {
+       char *startmsg = "start\n";
+       if (strncmp(buffer,  startmsg, strlen(startmsg)) == 0)  {
        
-        ret = send(newsockfd, "Type size of file in [Mb]\n", BUF_SIZE, 0);
+       char *msg = "Type size of file in [Mb]\n";
+        ret = send(newsockfd, msg, strlen(msg), 0);
  
         if (ret < 0) {  
          printf("Error sending data!\n");  
          exit(1);  
         }  
         
-            ret = recv(newsockfd, buffer, BUF_SIZE, 0);
+           /* to allow for a \0 that must be put at the end of what
+             * is received */
+            ret = recv(newsockfd, buffer, BUF_SIZE - 1, 0);
             if(ret < 0) {
              printf("Error receiving data!\n");  
              exit(1);
             }
          
+
+           buffer[ret] = '\0';
         fileSize = atoi(buffer);
          
-         ret = send(newsockfd, "Type Speed of internet in [MB]\n",
-BUF_SIZE, 0);   
+           msg = "Type Speed of internet in [MB]\n";
+   
+         ret = send(newsockfd, msg, strlen(msg), 0);
           if (ret < 0) {  
           printf("Error sending data!\n");  
           exit(1);  
@@ -131,6 +138,10 @@ BUF_SIZE, 0);
              printf("Error receiving data!\n");  
              exit(1);
             }
+
+           /* again, you must end a buffer read with a \0 if you
+             * want it to be checked with string routines */
+           buffer[ret] = '\0';
          
         speed = atoi(buffer);
         
@@ -139,6 +150,7 @@ BUF_SIZE, 0);
         buffer[BUF_SIZE] = sprintf(buffer,"Upload bude trvat %d:%d:%d\n",hours,minutes,seconds);
         
         
+       /* fd array has not been initialized, no pipe(2) call shown */
         if((write(fd[1], &hours, sizeof(int))) == -1){   /*problem is here */
             printf("write error\n"); 
             }
@@ -162,6 +174,8 @@ BUF_SIZE, 0);
     int fin;
     
 
+   /* no initialization of array fd, no pipe call shown in the snippet
+    * sent */
     if((read(fd[0], &fin, sizeof(int))) == -1){   /*problem is here */
     printf("read error\n"); 
     }
```

by the way, the problem is in neither one of the places your mark as candidates, but in that you insist in sending a text message by using `send(2)` without specifying the data length, so you send the full buffer, despite of what contents could it have.  Also, you read a full buffer and then use `strcmp(3)` to check for a string.  The client could buffer its output, and send you a full 1500 bytes block of data, starting with 'start\n' and that will result in not recognizing the starting subsequence.

I give up with your code, it required me to dedicate more than a full hour of my time and this is not what we all want.  My apologies.  Try to repair (and understand) all the modifications I've done to your code.  Next time, at least, format it adequately to be readable at least.  Indentation is fundamental to understand the program logic, and you have not dedicated enough time to make things easier to the people reading your code.  Please, read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to see how code must be sent to this forum.

Answer (score 0):

**connect() is missing after forking the child process.**

You have used **newsockfd** to send the data from the child process. **newsockfd** is the return value of accept system call. This is wrong.

Read:  https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tcp-server-client-implementation-in-c/

Comment: This is the only error he doesn't have... as he is writing a server.... :)  The code has plenty of errors, but `connect(2)` is not one of them.

Comment: @LuisColorado you are right.  :) :) My response is not an answer.  Just i had quick glance and understood he is beginner and provided a link for him to read the client/server .